# Can a non-blocking socket raise BlockingIOError from a reader/writer?

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, sockets, python-asyncio

Can a `sock.recvfrom` ever raise a `BlockingIOError` from a reader? Such as below

```py
sock.setblocking(False)

def reader()
    try:
        (data, addr) = sock.recvfrom(512)
    except BlockingIOError:
        # Can this ever be raised?

loop.add_reader(sock.fileno(), reader)
```

Similarly, can a `sock.send` ever raise a `BlockingIOError` from a writer?

```py
sock.setblocking(False)

def writer()
   try:
       bytes_sent = sock.send(data)
   except BlockingIOError:
       # Can this ever be raised?

loop.add_writer(sock.fileno(), writer)
```

I've experimented by trying to send/recv a fair bit of data, but it's never happened so far. Can it never actually happen, logically? If it can happen, under what circumstances?

Comment: Certainly, whenever EAGAIN would be raised, i.e. you read from a socket that had no buffered data, or wrote to a socket that had no buffer space.

Comment: @user207421 But wouldn’t the reader (or writer) only be triggered when there is buffered data (or had space)? Under what circumstances can the reader (or writer) be triggered where this isn’t the case? Can I _force_ this to happen as well, to investigate/test it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can [`BlockingIOError` in an asyncio reader] never actually happen, logically? If if it can happen, under what circumstances?

The answer to this question will almost certainly be system-dependent. Python itself doesn't provide any guarantees on the matter: functions like `os.read` and `socket.recv` just check the value returned by the underlying system call and, if it indicates an error, go on to convert the system-provided error to a Python exception.

So the question boils down to whether a read from a socket can fail with `EAGAIN` or equivalent if a preceding poll/select has indicated that it was readable (and the equivalent for writes). While that certainly sounds like an abnormal situation, the [`select(2)` man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html) **explicitly** warns of it under BUGS:

> Under Linux, `select()` may report a socket file descriptor as "ready for reading", while nevertheless a subsequent read blocks.  This could for example happen when data has arrived but upon examination has wrong checksum and is discarded.  There may be other circumstances in which a file descriptor is spuriously reported as ready.  Thus it may be safer to use `O_NONBLOCK` on sockets that should not block.

With non-blocking sockets, one should read "nevertheless a subsequent read blocks" as "nevertheless a subsequent read fails with `EAGAIN`", and the warning applies to this question. The issue is not specific to `select()` either; the [`poll(2)` man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html) also mentions spurious wakeups in its BUGS section, referring to the `select(2)` manual for details.

In other words, portable code should not rely on reads from "readable" sockets never raising `BlockingIOError`. Asyncio doesn't rely on it: it reacts to `EAGAIN` by simply [not completing the future](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/4c409beb4c360a73d054f37807d3daad58d1b567/Lib/asyncio/selector_events.py#L364), and thereby re-suspending the coroutine that awaits the read.